# Adding if statements to buttons on web page

Tags: java, html, css, web, button

Apologies - I did search google but I'm not sure

How do I change the url of a button depending on which page it's currently on?

I have a sticky header with anchors on some pages
I need something onClick that says

:if you're on "" page use this URL
else use this URL

I have situations where it will reload the page instead of just scrolling to the anchor, but I need some cross site navigation.

Sorry this isn't explained very well
Martyn

Comment: if this is a different page, then the button will be different or if you use templates, you can still send to it a different url

Comment: [What is the difference between Java and JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/245062/10082297)

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<button onClick="btnClick()">Click Me</button>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function btnClick(){
 if(window.location.href == "yourdesireyrl"{
  window.location = "youurl to go";
 }else{
  window.location = "otherurl"
 }
}
</script>
```